# Removing glare from monitor edges

Tags: technology

That's my monitor:

[image]

The seller website boasts:

> Antiglare coating: Ensures a clear view in brightly lit conditions.

This is true: the antiglare coating works well. But as the images proudly shows, the edges are damn shiny. How to remove the glare from monitor edges?

Answer (score 5):

It all depends. If you are into modding stuff, you could take the monitor apart and repaint it. If you aren't, take some matte black tape and tape over the edges. Problem solved.

Comment: Make sure to use a good paint designed for plastic, or prime with a strong solvent based primer, one that one continue to dissolve the case!

Comment: @BrownRedHawk Yep

Answer (score 4):

*With some own risk*, use fine sandpaper. Though I've used sandpaper (well, SiC paper) on a shiny e-reader without problems, there is always the chance that a slip will scratch the screen.

Aside: *Why* do manufacturers make display devices with glaring bezels, and worse yet, shiny screens? Camera lenses and eyeglasses have antireflective coatings, and high-quality optical devices are usually flat black.

Answer (score 1):

Try some magic tape or matt tape of color/shade of choice. It needs some precision and finesse to put on with a good finish. Also get the right width that you can do it in one go and a seamless manner.

Good thing about magic tape is you can always try it and remove it easily without leaving a trace if you change your mind later on.